# Nodemailer Invalid Login 535 when setting environment variables with ZEIT Now

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, vercel

When I use this configuration for Nodemailer:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: process.env.EMAIL_SERVICE,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
  }
});
```

Variables:

```
EMAIL_SERVICE: 'Hotmail',
EMAIL_USER: 'MyEmail@outlook.com',
EMAIL_PASSWORD: 'MyPassword'
```

And I send the email like this:

```
transporter.sendMail({
  to: email,
  subject: 'Confirmar cambio de contraseña',
  html: `Para cambiar la contraseña entre a <a href="${url}">${url}</a> <br> Este token solo dura 24 horas.`
});
```

In development it works perfectly but when I deploy this in Now, It throws me this error:

[image]

How can I resolve it?

Here a little example about this:

https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/NowProblemNodemailer

And here in now:

https://nowemail-owcypiqzsr.now.sh

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a [secret](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/environment-variables-and-secrets) and then add the environment variables to your `now.json`.

Run these commands once to add secrets in your ZEIT Now account (use `now switch` if you have multiple accounts).

```
now secret add email-service 'Hotmail'
now secret add email-user 'MyEmail@outlook.com'
now secret add email-password 'MyPassword'
```

Then add the `env` key to your `now.json` file like so:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [/* your builds go here */],
  "env": {
    "EMAIL_SERVICE": "@email-service",
    "EMAIL_USER": "@email-user",
    "EMAIL_PASSWORD": "@email-password"
  }
}
```